# Contract based Programming

Tags: code-contracts, spec#

Can someone explain the concepts that Spec# might be moving into C# 4.0, regarding Code Contracts?

- What are code contracts (Looks to be a compile time checking pattern)
- should I be excited about this?
- Am I correct in assuming that we move what would be runtime checks to compile time?

Thanks!

Comment: .NET Rocks had a decent podcast on spec#. Its a year ago since I listened to it, but im pretty sure they talk about your first and last bullet point. Its worth checking out for a fast overview of spec#.

Link: http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=237

Answer (score 3):

I personally am a big fan of a guy called Bertrand Meyer who wrote this book called [Object Oriented Software Contruction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136291554) and created a language called Eiffel which endoreses Design By Contract or Contract based programming.

1. Code Contract is a kind of agreement between 2 software entities that may or may not interact. More or less like interfaces but more precise.
2. I am not sure if everyone should or would be excited about this.
3. Your assumption is somewhat correct.

You might want to see this series of videos [link](http://www.eiffel.com/developers/presentations/dbc/partone/player.html?slide=)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good description of code contracts straight from [Microsoft Research](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/).  It sounds like the main benefits are:

- Improved testability
- Static verification
- API documentation (in code)